# Changing fix cell reference to dynamic one

Tags: vba, excel

It's been eons since I coded VBA, so most of that competence is there but very dusty. I've managed to create the following code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = Range("Resource").Column Then
  Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
End If

End Sub
```

It's very useful, given that we wish to affect the second column when something changes in first column. This is a bit of a limitation, so my question is twofold.

1. How to refer to a cell on *Target's* row but in column named "Hazaa"?
2. Is it possible to achieve without coding? (E.g. setting date in Bx when Ax changes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - here's an example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, Range("Hazaa").Column).Value
End Sub
```

2 - if I understand correctly, you might be able to use this formula & not need VBA.

```
=IF(AX1=BX1,TEXT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy"),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You simply need to use `Cells` or something like that :

   `Cells(Target.Row, HazaaColumn)`

HazaaColumn being here the number of your column **"Hazaa" that you need to set earlier in your code with a scan of you headers** (I do this pretty often to make my programs flexibles and avoid errors on columns changes)

Or with a range :

```
Range(ColLet(HazaaColumn) & Target.Row)
```

using custom function :

```
Public Function ColLet(x As Integer) As String
With ActiveSheet.Columns(x)
    ColLet = Left(.Address(False, False), InStr(.Address(False, False), ":") - 1)
End With
End Function
```

2. **You won't be able to detect changes** without VBA because you have to detect an event for that or have a reference table that you will need to update with VBA